# Indexing Json Strings from Spark Right away to Elasticsearch

Tags: java, json, scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

Is it possible to index JSON strings right away from Spark to Elasticsearch? I don't want to have any intermediate Scala case classes, or POJOS.

I am using Spark, Scala, and Elastic 5.5.

My code looks like the following:

```
 val s  = xml

    .map { x =>
      import org.json.XML

        XML.toJSONObject(x).toString

    }.top(1)

    spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(s).saveToEs("test/article")
```

However I keep getting:

```
org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Found unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) - failed to parse; Bailing out..
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.invokeListeners(TaskContextImpl.scala:138)
```

Even though I can index the JSON Strings using Kibana, or other ES clients.

In this code, I am just conversing an RDD with Strings of XML content to JSON, and then I try to index in ES.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the `.saveJsonToEs` method: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-write-json

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next approach if your object is already in JSON format:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark 
val jsonField = .....//some json                                     
val rdd = sc.makeRDD(jsonField)             
EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs")
```

If your object is not in JSON type before write operation, you can simplify your life and use the method which converts it to JSON format:

```
val persitedObject = .....//some json                                                 
sparkContext.makeRDD(persitedObject)
                      .saveJsonToEs("spark/docs")
```

For more details check [specification](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html).